# TSQL Finding maximum values in multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, max

In my query I need to find the supplier with the highest costs for every single year.

```
SELECT      YEAR(ORDERS.OrderDate),
            MAX(ORDERS.Freight) AS [Greatest cost]
FROM        ORDERS
GROUP BY    YEAR(ORDERS.OrderDate)
ORDER BY    YEAR(ORDERS.OrderDate) ASC
```

This code does give me the maximum cost per year, it doesn't give me the name of the supplier.

```
SELECT      YEAR(ORDERS.OrderDate),
            SHIPPERS.ShipperID,
            SHIPPERS.CompanyName,
            MAX(ORDERS.Freight) AS [Greatest cost]
FROM        ORDERS, SHIPPERS
WHERE       SHIPPERS.ShipperID = ORDERS.ShipVia
GROUP BY    YEAR(ORDERS.OrderDate),
            SHIPPERS.ShipperID,
            SHIPPERS.CompanyName
ORDER BY    YEAR(ORDERS.OrderDate) ASC
```

This code then gave me too much, as in, it gave me all the suppliers (with their highest numbers) for every single year, while I need the highest supplier per year.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: If one supplier had one order of `20` and a second supplier had three orders of `10` each, which supplier do you want for that year?

Comment: Let's say there are two suppliers in two years. In 1901 Supplier 1 has 10 and Supplier 2 has 11. Then in 1902 Supplier 1 has 8 and Supplier 2 has 15. What I want my query to do is to show me the name of the supplier for each year with the highest value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are likely several ways to do this. Here's one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/47d38/3/0

Test data:

```
create table ORDERS
(
  OrderDate datetime,
  ShipVia int,
  Freight int
);

create table SHIPPERS
(
  ShipperID int,
  CompanyName nvarchar(100)
);

insert SHIPPERS values (1, 'Shipper1'), (2, 'Shipper2'), (3, 'Shipper3');

insert ORDERS values
('2011-2-1', 1, 10),
('2011-3-1', 1, 20),
('2011-2-2', 2, 5),
('2011-3-2', 2, 10),
('2011-2-3', 3, 18),
('2012-2-1', 1, 10),
('2012-3-1', 1, 20),
('2012-2-2', 2, 25),
('2012-3-2', 2, 40),
('2012-2-3', 3, 18);
```

Query:

```
with A as
(
  select
    YEAR(O.OrderDate) as [year],
    S.ShipperID,
    SUM(O.Freight) as [totalFreight]
  from ORDERS as O
  join SHIPPERS as S on O.ShipVia = S.ShipperId
  group by YEAR(O.OrderDate), S.ShipperId
)
select A.*, S.CompanyName
from A
join SHIPPERS as S on A.ShipperID = S.ShipperID
where A.totalFreight >=ALL
  (select totalFreight from A as Ainner where A.[year] = Ainner.[year]);
```

Results:

```
year    ShipperID    totalFreight    CompanyName
2011    1            30              Shipper1
2012    2            65              Shipper2
```

Comment: This code works beautifully, but it seems like such a long way to get there. I had no idea it was this hard, I never could've found the answer myself. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
(
SELECT      YEAR(ORDERS.OrderDate),
            SHIPPERS.ShipperID,
            SHIPPERS.CompanyName,
            MAX(ORDERS.Freight) over (partition by YEAR(ORDERS.OrderDate), SHIPPERS.ShipperID) as max,
            row_number() over (partition by YEAR(ORDERS.OrderDate), 
                               order by ORDERS.Freight desc) as rn

FROM        ORDERS, SHIPPERS
WHERE       SHIPPERS.ShipperID = ORDERS.ShipVia 
) tt
where tt.rn = 1
```